# xmlParseEntityRef: no name' warnings while loading xml

Tags: php, xml

Hello stackoverflow community,

this code display the url for my sitemap, 
the connection work correctly and display the url list (not very well)
the error code i can see in the header

> This page contains the following errors:
>   error on line 2 at column 18210: xmlParseEntityRef: no name
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8') ?>
<?php 
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' ?>

<?php

define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','user');
define('DBNAME','database');
define('DBPWD','password');
$connect = new MySQLi(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPWD,DBNAME)or die(mysqli_error());

echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';
echo '<url>';

$query = $connect->query("select * from rss");
while($row=$query->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

echo '<loc>'.$row['link'].'</loc>';

}
echo '</url>';
echo '</urlset>';
?>
```

the code above output this (does this look correct ?)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url><loc>http://www.exemple.com/d/brown</loc>
<loc>http://www.exemple.com/d/blue</loc>
<loc>http://www.exemple.com/d/red/</loc> 
<loc>http://www.exemple.com/d/yellow</loc>
//more lines
</url></urlset>
```

i would like to know what i did wrong on this code
thanks you very much

(French Pierre)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem ,the error came from one field in the rss table contain a bad character ..., but i have added missing xml parameters

> lastmod, changefreq, priority

```
<?php 
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','user');
define('DBNAME','rss');
define('DBPWD','password');
$connect = new MySQLi(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPWD,DBNAME)or die(mysqli_error());

header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");  
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">";

    {

$query = $connect->query("select * from rss");
while($row=$query->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
  $url = $row["link"];
  $time = $row["when"];
  $lastmod = $time; 
  $datetime = new DateTime($lastmod);
  $timeresult = $datetime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP');

  echo "<url>
      <loc>$url</loc>
      <lastmod>$timeresult</lastmod>
      <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
";}}
?>
</urlset>
```

like this the output does not give error anymore
it does pass google validation

thanks you